# Change Shiro web configuration without restarting app

Tags: apache, shiro, rbac

Web-based Shiro RBAC uses web.xml and shiro.ini (or similar name) to configure roles/permissions in a web environment.

If I change roles for users in the web app, thus changing the shiro configuration, shiro doesn't reflect these changes until the web app is restarted..which of course isn't good for a production environment.

Apache Shiro docs/web site goes into great detail about creating roles/caching etc., but nothing about reloading the configuration at runtime in a web environment.
Note that in a non-web environmnet, if the .ini file is changed, by default Shiro reloads the configuration. Not so in a web.xml-based implementation (afaict).

Does anyone know a solid straightforward way to reload Shiro configuration without having to restart the web app?

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: Where are you storing user and roles? DAtabase, LDAP, ...

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment, but the answer is in the original post. From some further research on this, it looks like you can't auto-refresh shiro using its buit-in mechanisms - you have to use a db, Spring plugin-in or similar - the ini file is read once then that's it. It is possible to write a custom plugin that will read a file, but that's not part of shiro.